# Как убрать из строки лишние числа?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Нужно не позволять пользователю вводить в EditText номер телефона. Input фильтр не подойдет потому можно его скопировать и вставить. Фильтр пропустит. Реализую используя doAfterTextChanged

Как мне убрать из строки лишние числа? Нужно удалить все цифры после 6.
афывоафыа1234567890 -> афывоафыа123456

```
    private fun restrictMaxNumbers(maxCountNumbers: Int) = with(binding) {
    if (maxCountNumbers != ERROR_NUMBER_COUNT) {
        var ignore = false
        inputText.doAfterTextChanged {
            if (!ignore) {
                ignore = true
                val formattedString = removeExcessDigits(it.toString())
                it?.replace(START_POSITION, it.length, formattedString)
                ignore = false
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun removeExcessDigits(textString: String): String {
    val isStringContainDigits = textString.any { it.isDigit() }
    return if (isStringContainDigits){
        // how?
    } else {
        textString
    }
}
```

Comment: text.Replace('7890', ''); ? xd

Comment: цифры могут быть любые

Comment: android:maxLength="15"?

Comment: maxLength 50 но нужно ограничить чтоб юзер не ввел номер телефона

Comment: не актуально, решил с помощью изменения валидации в инпуте

Answer (score 0):

Посимвольно прочитай строку и проверь каждый символ на вхождение в диапазон от 49 до 54 - это  ASCII коды единицы и шестёрки, соответственно.

Вот пример на C#, возможно понадобятся минимальные доработки, но идея одна:

```
        string input = "афывоафыа1234567890";

        StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder(50);

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] >= 49 && input[i] <= 54 && number.Length <= 50)
            {
                number.Append(input[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: мне нужно ограничить ввод номера телефона в строку максимальная длина которой 50

Comment: Можно вместо input.Length написать что-то типа Math.Min(input.Length, 50). Лучше в вопросе сразу писать про 50

Comment: @Novikov в if добавил условие "number.Length <= 50", теперь будет браться только 50 цифр от 1 до 6. Если ответ помог, отметь галочкой как принятый. Ну и лайк приветствуется)